¿Como integrar redsys con php, enviar token generado insite?
Estoy tratando de integrar redsys con js y php. Basicamente he usando el modo insite: con js muestro el formulario y supuestamente envío el pago listo recibo el token que se supone debo recibir.
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/NC/sandbox/redsysV3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="card-form" />
    <form name="datos" method="POST" action="<?php echo "./redsys-config.php"; ?>">
        <input type="" name="submitPayment" value="1">
        <input type="" id="token"></input>
        <input type="" id="errorCode"></input>
        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>



    <script>
        function merchantValidationEjemplo() {
            //Insertar validaciones…
            alert("Esto son validaciones propias");
            return true;
        }


        window.addEventListener("message", function receiveMessage(event) {
            console.log(event)
            storeIdOper(event, "token", "errorCode", merchantValidationEjemplo);
        });



        function pedido() {
            return "pedido" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
        }

        var insiteJSON = {
            "id": "card-form",
            "fuc": "999008881",
            "terminal": "1",
            "order": pedido(),
            "estiloInsite": "twoRows"
        }

        getInSiteFormJSON(insiteJSON);
    </script>
</body>

</html>

Pero después me he perdido. No se que debo hacer con ese token que se ha generado.
He estado buscando información pero no logro encontrar nada. Me he quedado sin saber que paso seguir a partir de ahí.
Buscando en encontrado esto
<?php

    include 'apiRedsys.php';
    $miObj = new RedsysAPI;


    if (!empty($_POST)) {

        $version = $_POST["Ds_SignatureVersion"];
        $datos = $_POST["Ds_MerchantParameters"];
        $signatureRecibida = $_POST["Ds_Signature"];


        $decodec = $miObj->decodeMerchantParameters($datos);
        $kc = 'sq7HjrUOBfKmC576ILgskD5srU870gJ7';
        $firma = $miObj->createMerchantSignatureNotif($kc, $datos);

        if ($firma === $signatureRecibida) {
            echo "FIRMA OK";
        } else {
            echo "FIRMA KO";
        }
    } else {
        if (!empty($_GET)) {

            $version = $_GET["Ds_SignatureVersion"];
            $datos = $_GET["Ds_MerchantParameters"];
            $signatureRecibida = $_GET["Ds_Signature"];


            $decodec = $miObj->decodeMerchantParameters($datos);
            $kc = 'sq7HjrUOBfKmC576ILgskD5srU870gJ7';
            $firma = $miObj->createMerchantSignatureNotif($kc, $datos);

            if ($firma === $signatureRecibida) {
                echo "FIRMA OK";
            } else {
                echo "FIRMA KO";
            }
        } else {
            die("No se recibió respuesta");
        }
    }

    ?>

Pero realmente no logro entender bien como se usa y pues la documentación no es la mejor. ¿Cómo envío el token, que hago con él?.
Ese ejemplo dice genera una firma, pero igual no entiendo que hacer después de ahí.
¿Que estoy haciendo mal?
